# KDE connect unable to detect devices on same wifi network

Tags: 20.04, kde-connect

I m facing problem on kde connect running on **Ubuntu lts 20.04**. I using using WiFi via **USB wingle device** plugged-in a usb power hub. My phone and laptop remain connected to this same network but kde connect shows on laptop as well as phone (realme XT) that now other device on this WiFi network. But when I connect **USB wingle to laptop's USB port** and then run kde connect run on them both phone and laptop detect each other quite fine. so then whats the issue??????

Answer (score 3):

Eventually, I found out the solution to my problem.
The true culprit was my wifi network which not allowing the communication between two connected devices. So here is the solution
go to your router settings and `turn off` the option `access point(AP) isolation` which dont allow the communication between the devices on the same network.
for me settings were at the following place but it may varry router to router

```
router>admin page>settings>wlan>wlan advanced settings>ap isolation>turn off
```

then your devices would be able to communicate with each other being on the same wifi network
admin for most of the routers can be accessed at

```
192.168.1
```